# Submit Button in table is not working

Tags: laravel, forms, submit

my submit button in the following script is not working. What I have to chance that my submit button leads me to my route -> controller -> function?

```
<div class="panel-body">     
                    <table>  
                        <thead>    
                            <tr>
                                <th class="col-md-2">User</th>
                                <th class="col-md-2"> Gruppe</th>
                            </tr>  
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {!! Form::open(array('route'=>'store.exclusion')) !!}  
                            @foreach($members as $member)
                            <tr>
                                <td class="col-md-2" name="member" value="{{$member->member}}">{{$member->username}}</td>
                                <td class="col-md-2" name="idgroup" value="{{$member->idgroup}}">{{$member->groupname}}</td>
                                <td class="col-md-2">{{Form::submit('Ausschließen',['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        {!! Form::close() !!} 
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you're not actually submitting anything. all of your references in the foreach loop are in a td... not in an input of some type